# javascript get return value from async function in image src

Tags: javascript

I have a div in my React app like:

```
<div className="profile_image" style={{backgroundImage: 'url('+ process_image(url, function(img){ return img}) + ')'}}>
```

Here `process_image(url, function(img){ return img})` is a function which returns image. But it does not display the image.

What is wrong ??

If I do :

```
process_image(url, function(img){ 
    console.log(img)
    return img
})
```

On doing `console.log(img)` it gives me the image url.

Need help

Comment: `process_image` does not *return* the image. It returns nothing (as far as we know). It *fires a callback* which returns something (which goes nowhere).

Comment: Then how should I get the image from that function ??

Comment: Do the asynchronous call **in the controller**, instead of `return img` use `$scope.img = img`, and use just `img` in the template. Or something to this effect.